# Posting an array of checkboxes is not working with Zend-Server but works with LAMP: maybe a problem of settings?

Tags: php

I'm trying to pass through POST an array of checkboxes but this time it's not working (i've done the same things other times and everything was ok)

In a foreach loop i have this code to create the checkboxes:

```
$out .= "<td><input type='checkbox' value='$ordiniRiga->idRiga' name=\"etichetteArray[]\" id='mioId' ></td>";
```

But if i var_dump the $_POST (after checking all the checkboxes) i find that the array is NULL!(all the values ar numbers)

```
array(10) {
  ["idRiga1"]=>
  string(2) "30"
  ["idRiga2"]=>
  string(2) "31"
  ["etichetteArray"]=>
  NULL
  ["idRiga3"]=>
  string(2) "32"
  ["idRiga4"]=>
  string(2) "33"
  ["idRiga5"]=>
  string(2) "34"
  ["numRighe"]=>
  string(1) "5"
  ["idOfferta"]=>
  string(2) "32"
  ["idOrdine"]=>
  string(2) "12"
  ["submitEtichette"]=>
  string(16) "Stampa etichette"
}
```

Any idea of why this is happening?I'm using PHP 5.3 and Zend Server.

EDIT - The form it's really complex, i've created this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/tVwLS/1/ so that you can see it.

EDIT - i0ve tried out the code on a LAMP and it works ok. Does anyone know if there is some kind of configuration that allows posting arrays?

Comment: When you post are any of the check boxes checked?

Comment: post some of the generated html code

Comment: @sydenam Yes, they are checked, otherwise etichetteArray is not posted at all

Comment: What data type is $ordiniRiga?

Comment: it's an object (the class is stdClass)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was only with my home installation of zend_server.

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the [] characters at the end of the name attribute, this may cause the problem.

Comment: I tried, but it posts the value of the last checkbox that is checked

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem here is that checkboxes do not send their values to the server unless they are CHECKED.

There are a couple of other things wrong with this code (though they are probably not the root cause of your problem) -

1. You should not assign the same ID to multiple checkboxes.
2. Ideally the attributes of an HTML tag should be enclosed in double quotes (").
3. The way you are writing the value attribute, it will not be the value you expect. You probably meant to write `value='".$ordiniRiga->idRiga."'`.

Comment: they are checked, otherwise in the post i would not see etichetteArray, the value is correct because a property of an object is converted in php when you include it in double quotes